# Why is Satsuki and Mei's mother in the hospital?

Tags: my-neighbor-totoro

In *My Neighbor Totoro*, their mother is away from home in a hospital for an unspecified illness. At one point, they believe she may be able to come home if only for a visit, but the sickness gets worse and she is unable to leave the hospital.

### What illness is keeping Mrs. Kusakabe in the hospital?

Comment: Master Miyazaki's mom suffered tuberculosis - why that type of disease comes in to some of the films.

Comment: @phantom42: Is there anything more I can add to my answer to improve it for you?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Tuburculosis as per [the FAQ](http://www.nausicaa.net/miyazaki/totoro/faq.html#mother):

> It was implied that her illness was tuberculosis. In the novelized version of "Totoro" (illustrated by Miyazaki), it was stated that Mom was suffering from TB. Shichikokuyama Hospital, where she was staying, had a good reputation for treating TB, and that's why they moved there. The house they moved into was originally built a long time ago by a rich city man whose wife was suffering from TB. Granny used to work as a domestic for this lady, but the lady died. That's why the house is somewhat different from the other village houses, more Westernized, with gables.
>
> This is a bit autobiographical: Miyazaki's mother suffered for many years from spinal TB, and she was away from home for a long time.

Comment: A *lot* of people have TB in Miyazaki's works. I always wondered why.  Thanks for answering the question I never got to ask!

Comment: @Axelrod: At the risk of stating the obvious, it's partly also because, in the time periods many of his pieces are placed in, a lot of people had TB. Kind of like why so many people smoke in older movies. :)

Comment: @Axelrod in what other movies of his do people have TB?

Comment: @coburne The Wind Rises, for one

Comment: @Axelrod Beyond what FuzzyBoots said, TB as a disease was  romanticized in Japan, which added greatly to it's visibility. A good short essay on TB in Japanese history is here: http://lang.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~mfukuda/english.html

Comment: @coburne Why not post that as a separate question? ;)

Comment: @robbat2 Thank you! I love learning on this site!